# iFrame URL stucked

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

iframe URL stuck when going back to home page

I have created a website using WordPress and I link a page to a .aspx URL.  Since I wanted to hide the URL since it contains an IP address, I added an iFrame code. It works; however when I go back to the home page. the URL stuck on the page that I added the iFrame

website: philippineextremesports.com

page: RECORDS

```
<style>
body
{
margin: 0!important;
}
</style>
<iframe scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" border:none; src="http://122.54.139.226:86/pxswebportal/records.aspx" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</iframe>
```

To replicate:
-go to the site
-click records
-click home
-the URL remains http://records.philippineextremesports.com/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are browsing the site from within the iframe, not the actual top-level page. Without knowing why you are doing this, it is hard to say how to 'fix' this as it's the expected behavior.

I might suggest loading the main header, footer, etc. as part of the top level page and only include the iframe where needed for whatever it is, but I can't see what the iframe content is since it doesn't load.

Comment: we wanted the records page to redirect to:

http://122.54.139.226:86/pxswebportal/records.aspx

and we want to hide that URL.

Comment: Maybe I need to adjust the iframe properties.

Comment: @Nailroar You can't do what you want using iframes. Why can't that records page just be part of the main site at the proper domain?

Comment: Is it possible to have a .aspx running on a linux platform?